# Why MASM saves data when ctrl pressed?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, masm, dosbox

This is my first question.
The essence of the program is to read the line character by character and prohibit extraneous characters, such as F1, F2, Insert keys etc. or combinations with CTRL (Ctrl+c => heart symbol)

Part of my code below:

```
main:
    mov si, 0
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds, ax
    lea dx,message 
    mov ah, 09h     ;print message
    int 21h
    mov ax, 40h                     ; load segment into AX
    mov es, ax
read_loop:        
    mov ah, 00h
    test byte ptr es:[17h], 04h     ; is CTRL pressed?
    jnz read_loop
    int 16h
    cmp al, 0       ;check ASCII
    jne ASCII
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h
    jmp read_loop
ASCII:
    cmp ah, 14
    je read_loop
    cmp al, 13      ; ENTER?
    je next
    test byte ptr es:[17h], 04h     ; is CTRL pressed?
    jnz read_loop
    mov str_record[si], al
    mov ah, 02h     ; display
    mov dl, al
    int 21h
    inc si
    cmp si, 40  ;check max_len
    je next
    jmp read_loop
    
next:
    cmp str_record[0], '$'
    je quit
    mov al, 3
    int 10h
    mov di, 0
    mov ax, 3
    int 10h
    
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 2
    mov dl, 15
    int 10h
```

I am trying to check ctrl is pressed with [Keyboard Shift Status Flags](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/58-keyboard_shift_status_flags.html) but when I release the key, then all the buttons that I pressed along with CTRL are printed

Comment: This seems rather vague and confused. MASM only assembles your code, it has no role when you execute the resulting binary. The problem description sounds like you are on a PC architecture, but these sorts of details should definitely be spelled out in the question (and probably also reflected in the tags).

Comment: The fact that you don't call `int 16h/ah=00h` doesn't mean the keystrokes are lost. An interrupt will be generated anyway and the BIOS will read and buffer the code. Even if you disable interrupts, a few scancodes are buffered by the keyboard controller. If you don't want CTRL+XX combination it's better to read and ignore those characters. You need to use `int 16h/ah=01` probably along with `ah=02` and use `int 16h/ah=00` only when there's a keystroke (that by then you know if must be ignored or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> cmp al, 0       ;check ASCII
> jne ASCII
> mov ah, 00h
> int 16h
> ```

Asking a second time after receiving 0 would be typical for how certain DOS keyboard related functions operate. The BIOS keyboard functions don't work that way!

The more practical solution to not allow special keys disturb your results, is to only accept keys that have an ASCII code of 32 or more. The one exception being <kbd>Enter</kbd> of course.

```
read_loop:        
    mov  ah, 00h
    int  16h
    cmp  al, 13      ; ENTER?
    je   next
    cmp  al, 32      ;check ASCII
    jb   read_loop
    mov  str_record[si], al
    mov  ah, 02h     ; display
    mov  dl, al
    int  21h
    inc  si
    cmp  si, 40      ;check max_len
    jne  read_loop
next:
```